# Использование доступа в Django используя is_staff is_superuser

Tags: python, django

Всем привет не могу разобраться.
Хочу запретить во view в частности CreateView создавать записи пользователям, если у него не стоят галочки is_staff или is_superuser. Подскажите как это правильно сделать? Использую классы generic.

Comment: Используйте PermissionRequiredMixin

Comment: PermissionRequiredMixin  мне не подходит.  У меня выше конкретный вопрос с помощью is_staff is_superuser как это сделать.

Comment: Тогда делать проверку: if not request.user.is_staff

Comment: Вот именно. А в каком методе делать проверку? Эта проверка нужна мне до создания пустой формы, чтоб если галки is_staff не было форма не отобразилась и была переадресация на главную. С помощью  класса View я знаю как это сделать, а вот с помощью CreateView не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Тема закрыта всем спасибо!

Классы generic наследуются от BaseUpdateView в котором есть как и в классе View методы get и post то есть их можно переопределить.

```
class UserViewList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'userlist.html'
    model = CustomUser
    paginate_by = 15
    context_object_name = 'users'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            self.object = None
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('home')
            
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            self.object = None
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
        return queryset
```